# Dataframe encoding

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

Is there a way to encode the index of my dataframe? I have a dataframe where the index is the name of international conferences.

`df2= pd.DataFrame(index=df_conf['Conference'], columns=['Citation1991','Citation1992'])`

I keep getting:
`KeyError: 'Leitf\xc3\xa4den der angewandten Informatik'`

whenever my code references a foreign conference name with unknown ascii letters.

I tried:

```
df.at[x.encode("utf-8"), 'col1']

df.at[x.encode('ascii', 'ignore'), 'col']
```

Is there a way around it? I tried to see if I could encode the dataframe itself when creating it, but it doesn't seem I can do that either.

Comment: Maybe, you could post an example of the commands you tried with a data sample

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you're not using csv, and you want to encode your string index, this is what worked for me:

```
df.index = df.index.str.encode('utf-8')
```

Answer (score 11):

Setting up the encoding should be treated when reading the input file, using the option [`encoding`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html)

```
df = pd.read_csv('bibliography.csv', delimiter=',', encoding="utf-8")
```

or if the file uses `BOM`,

```
df = pd.read_csv('bibliography.csv', delimiter=',', encoding="utf-8-sig")
```

Comment: I actually saw that before posting, but it didn't help me as I'm not reading from a csv unfortunately. I'm reading from an sql comment. So i'm using pd.read_sql(). Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Just put "u" in front of utf8 strings such that

```
df2= pd.DataFrame(index=df_conf[u'Conference'], columns=[u'Citation1991',u'Citation1992'])
```

It will work.

Comment: What does the "u" mean?

Comment: "u" is a prefix for creating Unicode strings. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#unicode-strings