# How to extract features from text data set?

Tags: python

I try to tokenize the text file that i get from my zip folder but i am facing this error

**My Error**

```
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dataframe encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30156012/dataframe-encoding)

Answer (score 0):

Add `r` to your`C:\Users\killer\Desktop\User1.txt` so the backslash become `\\` instead of `\` because `\U` in `Users` is being interpreted as a start of an unicode

```
pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\killer\Desktop\User1.txt")
```

Or you can escape it manually or just change `\` to `/`

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is right but there are some characters that can't be read (not Unicode characters). This is because the file path you have given as `\U` (from `\User`) will by default be recognized as an escape sequence character and is unknown. For a file path to be recognized as one, you have to:

A) write it with `\\`, for eg. `"C:\\Users\\killer\\..."`

B) write it with `/` , for eg `"C:/Users/killer/..."`

C) use `r` in front, for eg. `r"C:\Users\killer\"` to use it as raw text, ie, everything is text and no escape sequences, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

`Data = pd.read_csv("C:\Users\killer\Desktop\User1.txt", sep=", ")`

Just add => , `sep=", "` at the end of the file you want to read.

**Note** that in quotation marks add what separates the text. In most cases, the text is separated by a comma "," but you can check the file by opening  it with your default text reader to see what separates it.